# Creating a dictionary, extracting array of average

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to do return years, average of grade for each year. 
What I was trying to do was to create a dictionary that fits year:grade, then get another dictionary of year:sum_of_grade then so forth.

It's from csv file, which has two headers: year and grade

```
Year  Grade
2001  100
2002  99
2001  88
2003  11
2005  55
```

There are many more, but I don't think it's necessary to have whole data.

```
def construct_values(file):
    """
    Construct the values needed to graph the average grade of the class over time

    Parameters
    ----------
    file_path: A string. Absolute path to file.

    Returns
    -------
    years: array of integers
    average_grades: array of floats
    """
    years, average_grades = [], []
    grades = []
    d = {}
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            year, grade = (s.strip() for s in line.split(','))
            years.append(year) # array year
            grades.append(grade) # array grade
            d = dict(zip(years,grades)) # dict year:grade

        for i,j in d:
            # i for count frequencies of years
            # j for summation of grades
            # j/i for average grade and extract as array


        return years, average_grades
```

I tried to be clear, but if it's still not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem when you use this:

`d = dict(zip(years,grades)) # dict year:grade`

Take your input data as example, it will generate a dict like:

```
{2001: 88, 2002: 99, 2003:11, 2005: 55}
```

Because when there are duplicate key during construct dictionary, the value is override.

So, to achieve this, I recommend to use another dict generate method, do something like this:

```
def construct_values(file):
    """
    Construct the values needed to graph the average grade of the class over time

    Parameters
    ----------
    file_path: A string. Absolute path to file.

    Returns
    -------
    years: array of integers
    average_grades: array of floats
    """
    years, average_grades = [], []
    # grades = []      This variable don't need anymore
    d = {}
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            year, grade = (s.strip() for s in line.split(','))

            # here is the begin line difference from your code
            if year not in d:
                d[year] = [int(grade), 1]
            else:
                d[year][0] += int(grade)
                d[year][1] += 1

        for year, grade_info in d.items():
            years.append(year)
            average_grades.append(grade_info[0] / grade_info[1])
            # end difference from your code

        return years, average_grades
```

In the middle dictionary ***d***, the value save information about [sum_of_grade, times_appeared_in_the_year], so when you iterate the dictionary, you can easily use *sum_of_grade / times_appeared_in_the_year* to calculate average.

And so, you don't need to use additional variable *grades*

Comment: Whats up with i in years.append()? Is it supposed to be year? Also, I don't get how grades can append in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, it's year.  The grade is append here: ```d[year] = [grade, 1]```, when you first meet *2001, 100*.  The middle dictionary will be {2001: [100, 1]}, and then meet *2001, 88*.  The middle dictionary will be {2001: [188, 2], 2002: [99, 1]}.  Because you just want to return average grade, so I think we can save the sum of grade, and the number of grades in a list.  It's unnecessary to append an actual grade value.

Comment: Your codes work, but this doesn't consider orders does it? cuz it is shuffled all arond, not starting from 2001 for instance.

Comment: nvm I did sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you see a table (csv-file being one) you should think pandas (my opinion).

Here is a pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = """Year,Grade
2001,100
2002,99
2001,88
2003,11
2005,55"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))

year_grade = {k: list(v) for k,v in df.groupby("Year")["Grade"]}
year_avg_grade = df.groupby("Year")["Grade"].mean().to_dict()
```

**year_grade:**

```
{2001: [100, 88], 2002: [99], 2003: [11], 2005: [55]}
```

**year_avg_grade:**

```
{2001: 94, 2002: 99, 2003: 11, 2005: 55}
```

Comment: very true. I understand pandas work great here. But for some reason, this assignment prevents me from using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

While created as `dict(zip(years,grades))` duplicate key won't allow in dictionary. So better to use an alternative method other than dictionary.

Some thing like this.

```
from itertools import groupby
combined = zip(year,grade)    
for n,g in groupby(sorted(combined, key = lambda x:x[0]),key=lambda x:x[0]):
    grades = [int(i[1])for i in g]
    print 'year : %s average : %s' %(n,sum(grades)/len(grades))
```

Result:

```
year : 2001 average : 94
year : 2002 average : 99
year : 2003 average : 11
year : 2005 average : 55
```